# Advanced Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

[image]

I am trying to implement this `listview` in my messaging app but m confused how to do it. Can anyone please suggest me any `idea` or provide me some `resources or samples`. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can make this ListView by assigning different margin to it's list items, the difficult part is to figure out a way to draw this line which passes through each image.

Comment: @eric247 I guess the different margins are tricky to get smooth for pixel-scrolling. It would get even trickier if the texts are supposed to be shortened with … depending on the space available. Setting the listView transparent with a background image should work to draw the arc.

Comment: @Giszmo That is a cool idea to handle the arc! But since android has a wide range of screen sizes, it may not be the best solution. What i had in mind was, you could, get the number of list items currently being displayed,  then give margin the highest margin to the center items, and bit lesser to the next ones, such that the last and first item have 0 margin, and the central one has like 50, and the others have some value between 0 and 50 based on their position.

Comment: @eric247 that would be very jumpy with each new item that enters the screen or old one leaving the screen. The margins have to be calculated based on the exact pixel position.

Comment: @user3374345 try using this library, i think this may help you. https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout

Comment: I think the best option is to look at how google does it for Wear OS, particularly, adjusting the scale and margins in onLayoutFinished https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists